# No Database Instance in nopcommerce 3.90

Tags: nopcommerce-3.90

I am facing error in nopcommerce 3.90 when run the project at that also at sometimes it is working good but after sometimes it shows the error of "no database instance". I am surprised it shows this type of error. Because the normal thing I have done to run the nopcommerce project.

I have done these things:

- set the setting file by installation of nopcommerce.
- delete the bin folder of nopcommerce.
- clean the solution and rebuild it.

But still facing the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

"no database instance" this type of error occures when the Nopcommerce is not able to connect with the database. If you have created database locally then try to find SQL service and restart the service. But if you are having database being hosted on any other server then check you network connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
There are some of summery solution that i have mention as below
=> Since i had moved a live cart to a test server, the settings in the database for that cart had force ssl and also force www before any url. Also under Store settings i still had the domain info for that site which was now difrent in the test server. Once i noticed this and updated the database it all started working.
=> 
You try change settings.txt file:
DataConnectionString: Data Source=localhost/IP;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=DBUser;Password=DBPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
=> 
In my case I need config application pool for nopcomerce

my connection string 
DataProvider: sqlserver
DataConnectionString: Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=nopcommerce370;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False

I need set Application Pool Identity to user has access right to db
Check the image to details.
=>  Check also db permission.
=> try with
Data Source=9X.2XX.7X.XX\"yoursqlservenameinstance"
or
Data Source="yournamemachine"
or
Data Source="yournamemachine"\"yoursqlservenameinstance"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like

- Check setting file on App_data existing or not
- Check connectionstring is correct or not
- Check your SQL server working or stop by try connect
- Clear cache your browser

Answer (score 0):

Try This ``

```
Right click on the downloaded file (nopCommerce_3.40_Source.rar) ->select  properties -> press "Unblock".
```

and

```
and change connection string in Settings.txt file.
```